# Diff with different props Axios put request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, put, axios

I have a put request that updates some information in my database. I'm trying to use `diff` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-diff) to separate the unchanged values from the changed. But right it's not working.
I have it like this:

```
onSubmit={handleSubmit(props => {
  // props is the updated form values
  onSubmit(id, diff(item, props))
})}
```

Nothing is getting updated, but if I switch `item` and `props` around my `(onSubmit(id, diff(props, item)))`  my five values are getting updated, but messes with my DB layout, because it removes my other values inside of my DB.

I have suspicion that it has to do with my action:

```
export function updateSettings(id, item) {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log(item)
    axios
      .put(`${settings.hostname}/locks/${id}`, item)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'SETTINGS_UPDATED',
          payload: {
            item,
            id
          }
        })
        console.log('EFTER', item) // It's still the same
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

Since `item` here has the same value as `props` inside of my form.

Thanks for reading and hopefully we can solve this!

Comment: In the scope of your action creator function, you're just logging the same `item` twice, if this is the actual code here. That explains why it's the same. Maybe you want to look at `res.data` or something? And about the order of `diff(item, props)` vs. `diff(props, item)`, the first one should be correct, since `props` is the new object. I recommend to check in your browser's dev tools what is being sent with the PUT request to verify that it is what you're expecting.

Comment: The problem is that `res.data` is only the document's id, not the whole document itself with the changes.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "it's not working" then. Is `item` the right object? Does it contain only the changed attributes you want to send to the DB? If so, then something is going wrong on the DB end, or you're not sending it in the expected format. I don't think your action creator is relevant here.